# Spring boot service to download a file

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to create a restful service using spring boot which will download a jar located at the server `http:8080/someurl/{fileid}`. How should I do it?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? If so, please post whatever you have so that the community can help better

Comment: No. I have just created a service to upload a jar file. Now i want a service to download jar file

Comment: That's exactly my point. Have you done anything in the direction of making the restful service for downloading the jar?

Answer (score 13):

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/files/{fileID}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void getFile(
        @PathVariable("fileID") String fileName, 
        HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
            String src= DestLocation.concat("\\"+fileName+".jar");
            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(src);
            IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());
            response.flushBuffer();
    }
```