# How to return an HTML page from a RESTful controller in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, controller

I want to return a simple HTML page from a controller, but I get only the name of the file not its content. Why?

#### This is my controller code:

```
@RestController
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String welcome() {
        return "login";
    }
}
```

#### This is my project structure:

[[image]

Comment: try to add a servlet to direct to index.html ```@ServletComponentScan```  then add @WebSevlet(urlPatterns = "") MainIndex

Answer (score 46, accepted):

When using `@RestController` like this:

```
@RestController
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String welcome() {
        return "login";
    }
}
```

This is the same as you do like this in a normal controller:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    @ResponseBody
    public String welcome() {
        return "login";
    }
}
```

Using `@ResponseBody` returns `return "login";` as a String object. Any object you return will be attached as `payload` in the HTTP body as JSON.

This is why you are getting just `login` in the response.

Comment: I am confused. What is the problem and how to fix ?

Comment: @Itération122442 You should use Controller annotation for the class and you should remove the ResponseBody annotation from method named welcome()

Comment: lol i do not get why this is marked as correct, it does not tell the answer it just explains the problem

Comment: It doesn't return proper answer. Don't know why it is marked as correct.

Answer (score 48):

Follow below steps:

1. Must put the html files in resources/templates/
2. Replace the `@RestController` with `@Controller`
3. Remove if you are using any view resolvers.
4. Your controller method should return file name of view without extension like `return "index"`
5. Include the below dependencies:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
   </dependency>`
   ```

Comment: After adding `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf` dependency, the view was resolved

Comment: With just spring-starter-web dependency I was able to serve html pages located inside src/main/resources/static ,  by typing localhost: 8080/helloworld.html( the entire name).  But using thmleaf it automatically maps to the html files. SO 
MY QUESTION   is there any option to serve the files through rest end points by just including spring-starter-web dependency

Comment: Using @Controller solved the issue and returned the view as opposed to a string

Answer (score 28):

You can try using `ModelAndView`:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public ModelAndView index () {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.setViewName("index");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

Answer (score 24):

@kukkuz pretty much answered to the question 'why?'. For those who are still looking into  'how', accumulating what others have answered.

Using a RestController:

```
@RestController
public class MyRestController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView welcome() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("login.html");
        return modelAndView;
    }  
}
```

- pay attention that view name is: 'login.html' (full file name).
- also it is important where the file is located, by default login.html must be in resources/static or resources/public

You may set up an application parameter for a default suffix like:

```
 spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html
```

in this case view name must be without extension like 'login'.

Some suggested thymeleaf can be used.
means you have in your pom.xml dependencies something like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.4</version>
</dependency>
```

In that scenario login.html by default must sit in: resources/templates folder, and the call is similar only difference now is in a view name, since [.html](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#spring.thymeleaf.suffix) is used by tymeleaf as a default value.

```
//  fails by default
//  NO fail if spring mvc view suffix is set in properties e.g.: spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html
//  NO fail if thymeleaf is added, and there is a file login.html in a resources/templates folder.
@RequestMapping("/loginTest")
public ModelAndView loginTest () {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.setViewName("login");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

Using a Controller:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

  //gets html from a default 'resources/public' or 'resources/static' folder
  @RequestMapping(path="/welcome")
  public String getWelcomePage(){
      return "login.html";
  }

  //gets html from a default 'resources/public' or 'resources/static' folder
  @RequestMapping("/welcome1")
  public ModelAndView getWelcomePageAsModel() {
      ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
      modelAndView.setViewName("login.html");
      return modelAndView;
  }

  //  fails with 404 resource not found by default
  //  NO fail, if spring mvc view suffix is set in properties e.g.: spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html
  //  NO fail, if thymeleaf is added, and there is a file login.html in a resources/templates folder
  @RequestMapping(path="/welcome2")
  public String thisFails(){
      return "login";
  }
}
```

Comment: very complete answer. Just notice that Thymeleaf searches templates in 'classpath:/templates/` directory by default

Answer (score 6):

Replace `@Restcontroller` with `@controller`. `@Restcontroller` returns only content not html and jsp pages.

Answer (score 6):

I did three things:

- Put the HTML page in {project.basedir}/resources/static/myPage.html;
- Switch @RestController to @Controller;
- This is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/")
public String aName() {
    return "myPage.html";
}
```

**No particular dependency** is needed.

Answer (score 5):

Replace `@RestController` with `@Controller`.

Comment: It would be better if you add some comments explaining your answer.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `login.html`. And replace `RestController` with `Controller`

Answer (score 4):

The answer from Kukkuz did not work for me until I added in this dependency into the pom file:

```
<!-- Spring boot Thymeleaf -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

From the guide [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/).

As well as updating the registry resources as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17013442/2480714/).

It then started working just fine. If anyone in the future runs into the same issue and following the first answer does not solve your problem, follow these 2 other steps after utilizing the code in @Kukkuz's answer and see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not using Thymeleaf and the only way it worked for me was with `@Controller`
in the class and

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/")
public String index() {
    return "index.html";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old but maybe it helps someone. To do this in a RestController, return a String that is the actual HTML code, then the browser will know what to display.

Answer (score 2):

Already answered by @kukkuz & @Robby with @RequestMapping annotation
but we can also use with @GetMapping annotation.

```
@GetMapping("/index")
public ModelAndView welcome() {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.setViewName("index.html");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You get only the name because you return only the name `return "login";`. It's `@RestController` and this controller returns data rather than a view; because of this, you get only content that you return from method.

If you want to show view with this name you need to use Spring MVC, [see this example](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/).

Answer (score 0):

The `String` you return here:

```
 return "login";
```

Is actually the **whole content** what you send back to the browser.

If you want to have the content of a file to be sent back, one way is:

1. Open file
2. Read contents into String
3. Return the value

You can go by with this [answer on the question Spring boot service to download a file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28451523/1667004)

Comment: This is not working for `@RestController`

Answer (score 0):

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/")
    public ModelAndView welcome() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("login.html");
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

This will return the Login.html File. The Login.html should be inside the static Folder.

Note: thymeleaf dependency is not added

```
@RestController
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/")
    public String welcome() {
        return "login";
    }
}
```

This will return the String login

Answer (score 0):

Methods annotated with **@GetMapping** in classes annotated with **@RestController** may return views (JSP,HTML etc) in two ways

```
@GetMapping("/dummy")
public String renderDummyWebPage() {
    return "dummy.jsp";
}
```

However, this method has two **LIMITATIONS**

1. That JSP Page has to be present in **src/main/webapp** directory, otherwise if the view is present in sub-directory the return type has to be modified accordingly. For example, if the JSP page is present in **src/main/webapp/views** directory - it should return **views/dummy.jsp** as String instead.
2. If you have already configured ViewResolver of the application returning a simple String will not work and the String will be interpreted as a normal String instead of JSP view name.

---

To overcome these two limitations, you can return a ModelAndView instead.

```
@GetMapping("/dummy")
public ModelAndView renderDummyWebPage() {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.setViewName("dummy");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

---

I hope this answer would be helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify GET or POST method inside RequestMapping like this:-

```
@RestController
public class HomeController {

@RequestMapping(value="/", Method="GET")  //or Method="POST"
public String welcome() {
    return "/login";
}
}
```

Now if you request on this page it will return login.html page

Comment: This doesn't work as /login is send as request body as we are using @RestController

Answer (score -1):

The most correct and modern form is to use `IoC` to put dependencies into the endpoint method, like the *thymeleaf* `Model` instance...

```
 @Controller 
 public class GreetingController {
        @GetMapping("/greeting") 
        public String greeting(
            @RequestParam(name="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name, Model model) {
             model.addAttribute("name", name); 
             return "greeting"; 
             // returns the already proccessed model from src/main/resources/templates/greeting.html 
      }
 }
```

See complete example at: https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/

Answer (score -1):

```
@Controller
public class WebController {
@GetMapping("/")

public String homePage() {
    return "index";
  }
}
```

Comment: any description?

Comment: this will also work with spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue in Spring boot 3.0.7 and this worked for me:

Change your controller annotations to `@Controller` and `@RequestMapping`. The welcome method should use `@GetMapping` annotation.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping
public class HomeController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String welcome() {
        return "login";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can solve this in two ways:

**First way:** If you wish to keep using REST you have to you a `ModelAndView` object to render a HTML page. An example is being posted by Happy Nguyen and I am posting it once more here:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public ModelAndView index () {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.setViewName("index");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

**Second Way:** If it is not important weather you keep using REST or not, so you can just change the `@RestController` to `@Controller` and make sure that you have already added **Thymeleaf** template engine.