# Spring Boot fails to return JSON for a object but not for list of objects

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, controller, jackson

I am developing my first Spring Boot application and i ran into a weird problem. The configuration is very basic:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.pawsec</groupId>
    <artifactId>kitchen</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>kitchen</name>
    <description>The Kitchen restaurant system</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.pawsec</groupId>
            <artifactId>common</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

We have some Javascript code on a page calling these two services. When the controller returns a Guy object in the first method, we get an empty response:

```
    {data: "", status: 200, statusText: "", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
config: {adapter: ƒ, transformRequest: {…}, transformResponse: {…}, timeout: 0, xsrfCookieName: "XSRF-TOKEN", …}
data: ""
headers: {}
request: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: ƒ, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
status: 200
statusText: ""
: Object
```

When we return a List of Guy objects from the second method, however, we get the full Json structure

```
back:
{data: Array(3), status: 200, statusText: "", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
config: {adapter: ƒ, transformRequest: {…}, transformResponse: {…}, timeout: 0, xsrfCookieName: "XSRF-TOKEN", …}
data: Array(3)
0: {guyId: 1, name: "Walter Sobchak", age: 45}
1: {guyId: 2, name: "Jeffrey Lebowski", age: 42}
2: {guyId: 3, name: "Theodore Donald Kerabatsos", age: 39}
length: 3
: Array(0)
headers: {content-type: "application/json;charset=UTF-8", cache-control: "private", expires: "Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT"}
request: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: ƒ, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
status: 200
statusText: ""
: Object
```

The controller looks like this:

```
package com.pawsec.kitchen.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.pawsec.kitchen.model.Guy;

@RestController
public class GuyController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/get/guy/{guyId}", method=RequestMethod.GET,
            headers={"Accept=application/json"})
    public Guy getGuy(@PathVariable("guyId") int guyId) {
        Guy someGuy = new Guy(guyId, "Walter Sobchak", 45);
        return someGuy;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/get/guys", method=RequestMethod.GET,
            headers={"Accept=application/json"})
    public List<Guy> getGuys() {
        Guy walter = new Guy(1, "Walter Sobchak", 45);
        Guy theDude = new Guy(2, "Jeffrey Lebowski", 42);
        Guy donny = new Guy(3, "Theodore Donald Kerabatsos", 39);
        List<Guy> guys = new ArrayList<Guy>();
        guys.add(walter);
        guys.add(theDude);
        guys.add(donny);
        return guys;
    }

}
```

Strangely, if i call these two services from a browser, i get the correct Json structure for both the calls.

When i run a mvn dependency:tree, the expected Jackson dependencies that come with a basic Boot Project are there.

This is what the JavaScript code looks like:

```
return dispatch => {
        dispatch(fetchMenuStart());
        const url = 'https://boot.ourcompany.com:8443/get/guy/1'; 
        const headers = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }
        axios.get(url, headers)
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res); 
                dispatch(fetchMenuSuccess(res.data.categories, res.data.restaurant));
            })
            .catch(error => {   
                console.log("error", error);
                const errorMsg = 'There was an error fetching the menu';
                dispatch(fetchMenuFail(errorMsg)); 
            });
    };
```

Can anyone suggest what might be causing this or steps to test to figure out the issue?

New javascript example code:

```
const doesNotWork = 'https://boot.exmpledomain.com:8443/get/guy/1'; 
const doesWork = 'https://boot.exmpledomain.com:8443/get/guys'; 
const headers = {
    headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
    }
}
axios.get(doesNotWork, headers)
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res); 
    })
    .catch(error => {   
        console.log("error", error);
        const errorMsg = 'There was an error fetching the menu';
    });
```

Comment: did you set the content-type as application/json in the ajax call?

Comment: If you're getting the right response from the browser but incorrect from the js code, obviously there is some issue with the js code. Could you please add the js code snippet that you're using?

Comment: With which  url/path are you trying to access "/get/guy" ? ... I would expect `/get/guy/1`, `/get/guy/2` and `/get/guy/3` to work.. (Have you noted the "path variable" `{guyId}`?)

Comment: please provide JavaScript code from where you are calling the service

Comment: @xerx593 - this is just simplified example code to illustrate the issue

Comment: ..maybe show us "some Javascript code".

Comment: I added the JavaScript code

Comment: @MatsAndersson, have you fixed this error?

Comment: @MichałZiober no we have not. We have been waiting for some help here

Comment: @MatsAndersson, Since you get the proper response when call this via the browser. The problem is in your front-end code. Can you add the full front end code? Also, do add the code for the other request too

Comment: @MatsAndersson, I have set up `Spring Boot` app as in your example and it works for me. It must be a problem on client side. You use [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) library for loading data from the server. Why do you use `URL` with domain? Can not you just use `const url = '/get/guy/1';` Do you load data from other domain? Do you have any custom global configuration for `axios`? Also, server side response with `200` which means that server side returned empty string as a successful result.

Comment: @MichałZiober. Yes, the client is on a different domain from the services, which are in a Spring boot application, that provides our micro-services. The same axios config is used for all service calls. They all work except this particular one. If i call this service from a web browser, i can see clearly that the response is not empty. Also, if i call this URL from Postman, i get success and a response containing the correct data structure.

Comment: added javascript example code

Comment: have you told spring to convert the response string body into JSON? You either need to add `produces = "application/json"` as parameter of `@RequestMapping` annotation OR you can use `@ResponseBody` annotation at controller level.

Comment: Use @JsonSerialize for Guy class and add  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) on your method

Comment: Can you try using the ObjectMapper to serialize the model before returning the response in your controller class?

Comment: You're not specifying the return type .. 

`@RequestMapping(value="/get/guy/{guyId}", 
                method=RequestMethod.GET, 
                produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
)`

Comment: Thank you @agam. I tried what you suggested. I tried these and there was no change. Please understand that i can call both these services from a browser and they both return Json.

Comment: Thank you @EddieB. I tried this and we get the exact same results. Please understand that i can call both these services from a browser and they both return Json.

Comment: Thank you @RamachandraAPai. We have several Spring projects that all produce Json automatically, so moving to a solution where every controller method would have to use an ObjectMapper to manually produce Json does not sound like an attractive change. I hope i am not misinterpreting your reply. If i am, please let me know what you mean.

Comment: Thank you @sankar. I am fairly sure this is a non-Spring-solution. We have plenty of services that return Json representations of classes that aren't annotated (at)JsonSerialize. By calling these services from a browser, i can see that they both return Json.

Comment: We have made some more research on this. It seems that when we return our own classes (for example Guy), we get an error. If, however, we return for example an ArrayList or a String, we do not get this error. Also, an ArrayList<Guy> works fine.

Comment: Also some more info on the error itself: the calling javascript code get an empty string as return data and this error message: "xhr.js:173 Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://boot.exampledomain.com:8443/get/guy/1 with MIME type application/json. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details."

Comment: Agreed. Only hint I could think of is that Guy is a custom bean and rest all are built-in data types or collections. Looks like ajax is not able to interpret the model as json. By using ObjectMapper or Json Annotations as suggested by @sankar you clearly specify that you need the conversion. I will look for simpler ways if possible. Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: @MatsAndersson - If it works in the browser, your problem is not the backend. The moment the JSON goes on the wire, there's not type Guy, there's no "custom beans" and so on. The json is plain text and your JS frontend should know how to work with that. Can you add interceptors for the request and responses and paste the output on both? https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors

Comment: At first reading it seems to be a JavaScript problem, but here are some things you could try on the Spring side: 
1. Test your endpoints with Postman to get more details on headers and co (and send us the results), 
2. Remove _headers={"Accept=application/json"}_ from your endpoint (Spring processes and produces JSON as default), 
3. Try to accept id as String instead of int like _@PathVariable("guyId") String guyId_

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try changing the header to accept in the javascript

```
return dispatch => {
        dispatch(fetchMenuStart());
        const url = 'https://boot.ourcompany.com:8443/get/guy/1'; 
        const headers = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            }
        }
        axios.get(url, headers)
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res); 
                dispatch(fetchMenuSuccess(res.data.categories, res.data.restaurant));
            })
            .catch(error => {   
                console.log("error", error);
                const errorMsg = 'There was an error fetching the menu';
                dispatch(fetchMenuFail(errorMsg)); 
            });
    };
```

Comment: Yep... he's missing the 'Accept' header in the client as well as the return type on the server (produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)

Answer (score 1):

I have finally solved this issue by disabling CORS, with the following class:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Profile("devel")
@Configuration
public class WebConfig {

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**");
            }
        };
    }

}
```

I have also added the `@Profile` annotation to disable CORS only on development time.

By the way, the reason for the issue seems to be explained in:

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/services/network/cross_origin_read_blocking_explainer.md#Protecting-JSON

When returning an object, it is interpreted as a non-empty JSON object (such as `{"key": "value"}`). When returning a list, the same text is wrapped in squared brackets and it *passes the protection*.

Comment: Thank you for your input, Benjamin Valero

Answer (score 0):

As your javascript is on a different domain from the spring-boot service, you need to configure [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

This could be done globally adding `@CrossOrigin` like this :

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
public class GuyController {
```

Comment: Dont think this would be the issue, since the request which returns list of custom object works fine.

Comment: @MadhuBhat: I made a test with spring-boot & axiom and it works with 1 object and a list of object serving the JS from the spring-boot without any problems. Using different webservers I reproduced a CORB exception with 1 object that is not present with a list of objects, disabling CORS it works in both cases.

Comment: Sorry everyone, i've been sick a few days. I can add that we have multiple Spring-based systems running. They have hundreds of controller methods returning both our own classes and lists and other classes. We call these methods using this same javascript way and we have never had this issue before. This, however, is our first time we use a Spring boot application with its built-in Json support. It is also the first time we make the calls from a React client that is not integrated with the server side. Our other systems use JSP for the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

If you use spring, you should use `ResponseEntity` instead of directly returning the object:

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
```

This is how I write my controllers:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(USERS)
public class UserController {

  @Autowired
  private UserService userService;

  @Autowired
  private RoleService roleService;

  @Autowired
  private LdapUserDetailsManager userDetailsService;

  @GetMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public ResponseEntity<?> list(PagedResourcesAssembler<User> pageAssembler, @PageableDefault(size = 20) Pageable pageable, UserDTO condition) {
    Page<User> page = userService.findAll(pageable, condition);
    PagedResources<?> resources = pageAssembler.toResource(page, new UserResourceAssembler());
    return ResponseEntity.ok(resources);
  }

  @GetMapping(value = CoreHttpPathStore.PARAM_ID, produces= MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public ResponseEntity<UserResource> get(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    User user = userService.get(id);
    UserResource resource = new UserResourceAssembler().toResource(user);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(resource);
  }

  private void preProcessEntity(@RequestBody UserDTO entity) {
    if (null != entity.getPassword()) {
      userDetailsService.changePassword(entity.getOldPassword(), entity.getPassword());
    }
  }

  @PostMapping
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
  Long create(@RequestBody User user) {
    userService.insert(user);
    return user.getId();
  }

  @PutMapping(CoreHttpPathStore.PARAM_ID)
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
  void modify(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @RequestBody UserDTO user) {
    user.setId(id);
    preProcessEntity(user);
    userService.updateIgnore(user);
  }

  @DeleteMapping(CoreHttpPathStore.PARAM_ID)
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
  void delete(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    userService.delete(id);
  }

  @DeleteMapping
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
  void bulkDelete(@RequestBody Long[] ids) {
    userService.delete(ids);
  }
}
```

Comment: Using `ResponseEntity` is not a necessity at all.

Answer (score 0):

OK everyone, thank you so much for your efforts. It turns out that the solution suggested by @mpromonet (adding CrossOrigin annotation on the controller) solves this problem. I am still very curious to know why a method returning List works and one returning a Guy does not if this is a cross-origin issue. It does not seem logical and it makes the issue a lot harder to figure out.

Answer (score -1):

You have to add `@ResponseBody` annotation before your method.

```
@ResponseBody
public Guy ....
```

Comment: `@RestController` doesn't need `@ResponseBody` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38700790/how-to-return-a-html-page-from-a-restful-controller-in-spring-boot/38701146#38701146)