# How to return a hyperlink from spring boot controller?

Tags: java, spring-boot, get, request, httpresponse

I want to return a hyperlink in the response body for a get request using Spring Boot, but i am getting string as a response and not link

```
@GetMapping("/getLinkToFile/{id}")
public URL getLinkToFile(@PathVariable int id) throws Exception {
    URL base = new URL("https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/file_example_CSV_5000.csv");
    return base;
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking - are you wanting to view the response in a browser and expecting a hyperlink that you can click on ?

Comment: what type of response you want

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38700790/how-to-return-a-html-page-from-a-restful-controller-in-spring-boot

Comment: yes i want clickable link in response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try this one please , then you will get idea to do archive your problem

```
@GetMapping(value = "/test")  // just for samples 
  public String getLinkToFile() throws Exception {
    String body =
        "<HTML><body> <a href=\"https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/file_example_CSV_5000.csv\">Link clik to go</a></body></HTML>";
    return (body);

  }
```