# Is there a way to return HTML page from Restful Controller in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

I am currently making a file upload within my spring boot project. I am using rest controller for my controller as that is what is written within the tutorial that I am using https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-file-upload-download-jpa-hibernate-mysql-database-example/

However, I found out that apparently rest controller unable to display HTML page based on what is written here: [How to return a html page from a restful controller in spring boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38700790/how-to-return-a-html-page-from-a-restful-controller-in-spring-boot)

Is there a way for displaying my HTML page while retaining the rest controller?

this is my **controller**

```
@RestController
public class RekonsiliasiController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RekonsiliasiController.class);

    @Autowired
    private DBFileStorageService dbFileStorageService;

    @RequestMapping("/rekonsiliasi")
    public String index() {
        System.err.println("MASUK PAK EKO OI");
        return "rekonsiliasi";
    }

    @PostMapping("/uploadFile")
    public UploadFileResponse uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        DBFile dbFile = dbFileStorageService.storeFile(file);

        String fileDownloadUri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath()
                .path("/downloadFile/")
                .path(dbFile.getId())
                .toUriString();

        return new UploadFileResponse(dbFile.getFileName(), fileDownloadUri,
                file.getContentType(), file.getSize());
    }

    @GetMapping("/downloadFile/{fileId}")
    public ResponseEntity<ByteArrayResource> downloadFile(@PathVariable String fileId) {
        // Load file from database
        DBFile dbFile = dbFileStorageService.getFile(fileId);

        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(dbFile.getFileType()))
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + dbFile.getFileName() + "\"")
                .body(new ByteArrayResource(dbFile.getData()));
    }

}
```

and this is my **rekonsiliasi.html**

```
 <form method="POST" action="/uploadFile" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                          <input type="file" name="file" /><br/><br/>
                                          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                                      </form>
```

This is what I get currently, a blank page with a simple text

[image]

**UPDATE**

I tried to divide between the index and the file upload to the following.

RekonsiliasiController.java

```
@Controller
public class RekonsiliasiController {

    @RequestMapping("/rekonsiliasi")
    public String index() {
        System.err.println("MASUK PAK EKO OI");
        return "rekonsiliasi";
    }
```

FileController.java

```
@RestController
public class FileController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FileController.class);

    @Autowired
    private DBFileStorageService dbFileStorageService;

    @PostMapping("/uploadFile")
    public UploadFileResponse uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        System.err.println("CEK");
        DBFile dbFile = dbFileStorageService.storeFile(file);

        String fileDownloadUri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath()
                .path("/downloadFile/")
                .path(dbFile.getId())
                .toUriString();

        return new UploadFileResponse(dbFile.getFileName(), fileDownloadUri,
                file.getContentType(), file.getSize());
    }


    @GetMapping("/downloadFile/{fileId}")
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> downloadFile(@PathVariable String fileId) {
        // Load file from database
        DBFile dbFile = dbFileStorageService.getFile(fileId);

        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(dbFile.getFileType()))
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + dbFile.getFileName() + "\"")
                .body(new ByteArrayResource(dbFile.getData()));
    }

}
```

Now the HTML is showing perfectly fine but when I upload the file I got 403 Error. Before I tried to find the problem for this part, I'd like to know whether if there are some ways for displaying my HTML page while retaining the rest controller?

**EDIT** Delete the 'uploadMultipleFiles' method in FileController.Java and it still gets me 403 error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in your code in the controller method `uploadMultipleFiles`, you are actually calling the controller method `uploadFile` directly by treating it just like another method which is not ideal. The fact that you need to recursively call another controller endpoint means that it is a design flaw in itself. So , try to remove this bit of code by providing the logic in service layer to handle this scenario .

Secondly , splitting the view controller and the rest controller into two separate classes is the right approach. The `@RestController` annotation is designed to serve json response by default that is why we have the `@Controller` annotation which serves both **model and view**. The response code 403 that you receive has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Oh, it was my mistake when I made this post. I already delete the `uploadMultipleFiles` method and it still ends up with 403 error

Comment: Have you added any logs or tried debugging to understand why it is returning 403. Is your request reaching your endpoint ?

Comment: As I submit the uploaded file, it is successfully lead the link to `/uploadFile` however apparently after I check it again - Apparently, it didn't enter the method of `uploadFile`

Comment: Could you check the request that yoiu are initiating to verify that the multipart file and other parameters are correct in the request ?

Comment: Is there a way to check it? Since I have tried to put `System.err.println("Check")` in the very first line of my method. It doesn't show in my console despite it is directed to `/uploadFile` for the URL

Comment: @Gagak Are you using spring security ? If yes allow the url mapping . You can enable and  check the springboot access logs to understand the request recieved by the endpoint . It will help you understand if there is any issue with your request.

Comment: Oh, I tried to disable the CSRF token in the security and it works. However, I am not sure if it is advisable to do that or not.

Comment: @Gagak The csrf token needs to be added in the request as well if you enable it in security. It will fix your issues.