# Why is the html page not loading - using Spring boot, java, and thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

This is the Controller page:

@Controller
public class AppController {

```
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepo;

@GetMapping("")
public String viewHomePage() {
    return "index";
}

@GetMapping("/index")
public String logoutPage() {return "index";}

@GetMapping("/menu")
public String menuPage() {return "menu";}

@GetMapping("/register")
public String showRegistrationForm(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("user", new User());

    return "signup_form";
}

@PostMapping("/process_register")
public String processRegister(User user) {
    BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    String encodedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword());
    user.setPassword(encodedPassword);

    userRepo.save(user);

    return "menu";
}

@GetMapping("/users")
public String listUsers(Model model) {
    List<User> listUsers = userRepo.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("listUsers", listUsers);

    return "users";
}

public  List<Troops> getTroops() {
    List<Troops> TroopList = new LinkedList<>();
    try {
        // File path to the XML file.
        Path filePath = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\amani\\OneDrive\\WYWM\\Java\\Capstone 1\\dataset.xml");
        File file = new File(String.valueOf(filePath.toAbsolutePath()));

        if (file.exists()) {
            DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document = documentBuilder.parse(String.valueOf(filePath.toAbsolutePath()));
            // Reads the XML tagName of full_name and id.
            NodeList[] user = { document.getElementsByTagName("full_name"), document.getElementsByTagName("id") };

            for (int i = 0; i < user[0].getLength(); i++) {

                String fullName = user[0].item(i).getTextContent();
                int id = Integer.parseInt(user[1].item(i).getTextContent());
                Troops newTroop = new Troops(fullName, id);
                TroopList.add(newTroop);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("File not found");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    // Returns the TroopList with data from the XML file.
    return TroopList;

}




@RequestMapping(value = "/numasc", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public List<Troops> getNumAsc( ) {
    List<Troops> ascList = new LinkedList<Troops>();
    ascList.addAll(getTroops());
    ascList.sort((u1, u2) -> u1.getId() - u2.getId());
    return ascList;
}
```

When run the above - I get the following:

[{"fullName":"Maridel MacCostye","id":1},{"fullName":"Phineas Bonnet","id":2},{"fullName":"Oates McGillivray","id":3},{"fullName":"Curtice Comelli","id":4},{"fullName":"Phillis Wontner","id":5},{"fullName":"Bradley Hasell","id":6},{"fullName":"Carling Cokely","id":7},{"fullName":"Bertrand Samms","id":8},{"fullName":"Chiarra Trill","id":9},{"fullName":"Willie Balmadier","id":10},

but my html page for "/numasc" looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
  <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
  <title>Soldiers Deployed</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/webjars/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/webjars/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container text-center">
  <div>
    <form th:action="@{/logout}" method="post">
      <p>
        Welcome <b>[[${#request.userPrincipal.principal.fullName}]]</b>
      </p>
      <input type="submit" value="Sign Out" />
    </form>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>Soldiers Deployed</h1>
  </div>

  <div>

    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Full Name</th>

      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

      <a th:href="@{/menu}" class="button primary">Back to Menu</a>

      <tr th:each=" ${ascList}">
        <td th:text=${ascList.id}>ID</td>>
        <td th:text=${ascList.fullName}>Full name</td>>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Apart from having a table, my html pages are similiars and they are all working fine. I don't understand why the html page isn't being picked up.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return a html page from a restful controller in spring boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38700790/how-to-return-a-html-page-from-a-restful-controller-in-spring-boot)

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the @ResponseBody tag.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/numasc", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public List<Troops> getNumAsc( ) {
    List<Troops> ascList = new LinkedList<Troops>();
    ascList.addAll(getTroops());
    ascList.sort((u1, u2) -> u1.getId() - u2.getId());
    return ascList;
}
```

Instead use:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/numasc", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getNumAsc(Model m) {
    List<Troops> ascList = new LinkedList<Troops>();
    ascList.addAll(getTroops());
    ascList.sort((u1, u2) -> u1.getId() - u2.getId());
    m.addAttribute("ascList", ascList);
    return "numsac";
}
```

Comment: If I remove it I then get this error: Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
 And then about 100 lines which stack over isn't allowing me to post

Comment: change the return type to String for the getNumAsc() method and in the return statement specify the name of the html file you want to be loaded when you call /numasc.

When you use @ResponseBody, it returns the HTML file as a response body not a HTML file.

Comment: it then gives this error: Error resolving template [ascList], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [ascList], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

Comment: what is the name of the html file you want to be returned?

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/numasc", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getNumAsc( ) {
    List<Troops> ascList = new LinkedList<Troops>();
    ascList.addAll(getTroops());
    ascList.sort((u1, u2) -> u1.getId() - u2.getId());
    return "{name_of_your_html_file}";
}

Comment: I did that - same error: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/numasc.html]")
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/numasc.html]")

Comment: I figured it out - your answers really helped me understand it a lot better - thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

modified according to your working html routes...

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/numasc", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getNumAsc(Model model) {
    List<Troops> ascList = new LinkedList<Troops>();
    ascList.addAll(getTroops());
    ascList.sort((u1, u2) -> u1.getId() - u2.getId());

    model.addAttribute("ascList", ascList);

    return "numask";
}
```

Comment: is the return "numask" a type - did you mean to put numasc which is the same as the html file?

Comment: There is no more error and now I can see a table but the table is empty. I have put this in the html file: <tr th:each="ascList:${ascList}">

Comment: I figured it out - your answers really helped me understand it a lot better - thank you so much

Comment: numask ist the template name (html file)