# How to download a CSV file stored in server at location Temp/hello.csv

Tags: java, csv, spring-boot, server

I want to download a CSV file which at server on the location Temp\hello.csv using java code

1. I have the data. I am populating that data into a CSV file, hello.csv
2. This file I am saving/storing in server under \Temp folder
3. The CSV file gets stored at location Temp\hello.csv folder in server.
4. I want to download this file but I don't know how to do it using java code

Comment: If my answer helped you, you should accept it ;)

Answer (score 0):

This should work (from https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-async-output-stream):

```
@RequestMapping("/download")
public StreamingResponseBody handle() {
    return new StreamingResponseBody() {
        @Override
        public void writeTo(OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
            File file=new File("Temp\hello.csv");
            FileInputStream stream =new FileInputStream(file);
            IOUtils.copy(stream, outputStream);
        }
    };
}
```

But there are many other capabilities. ([Spring boot service to download a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28407215/spring-boot-service-to-download-a-file) , [Downloading a file from spring controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673260/downloading-a-file-from-spring-controllers) , ...)